# Create an array of JButtons with the Netbeans 6.5 GUI Builder

Tags: java, netbeans, jbutton

I want to create an array of JButtons with the GUI Builder (not actually writing the code, but drawing it). I can only figure out how to change the name of the element, not add it to an array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqGuiControlArray

Comment: So it can't be done via Netbeans then! I need to create 49 JButtons, and put them on the GUI, and then access them from the program.  I'll have to type it in by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find doing much "programmatically" will go beyond most GUI builders, other than for specific programmed-for exceptions.