# Creating an Array of JLabels

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, netbeans, jlabel

I'm trying to create 5 Jlabels using netbeans GUI Design, the Labels are supposed to display 5 different values.

I need to combine these 5 JLabels in 1 array of Labels. is there any options in the design that let me do that?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746325/create-an-array-of-jbuttons-with-the-netbeans-6-5-gui-builder.

Comment: I dont think there is any way of doing that

Answer (score 1):

use a Panel or an Internal Frame, then simply put your JLabels inside